# Recommended way to install a simple Py library using Make

Tags: python, module, installation

For my simple C library I have a simple Python wrapper using `ctypes`. I am now writing the `Makefile` for my library. In it under the `install` target I have:

```
install -m 644 mylib.py $(shell python3 -m site | grep $(PREFIX).*packages | cut -d \' -f2)/
```

This is something I contrived myself. I don't want to use `distutils` or all those multiple Python installation "solutions" because they are too convoluted for my simple requirements: Once the `.so` file is installed, all that is really needed for my library to be accessible from Python is for the `.py` interface to be in the correct `import`-able location. So I'm figuring a simple copy should do.

Does anyone foresee any problem with what I am doing? If so, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using setup-tools and uploading your source files to pipy.org, anyone on the world can install your project by simply typing `pip install <yourmodule>`.

Moreover, larger Python projects which happen to want to use your library will just have to list its name in a single line, either in a requirements.txt file, or on setup.py

if your project is not open source and you don't intend it to be accessible by "the world", the distutils solutions - no quotes needed - allow your project to be fetched from a private git repository, or even a prevate Python "Cheese Shop".

If you absolutely don't care about using the right way to do things, you might as well just drop a plain English line on your README telling the user to copy your ".py" file to any folder he likes - installation won't be as expected by Python users anyway.

Otherwise, just have a minimalist setup.py file and have a make line that goes `python setup.py install` - it certainly won't hurt (your library will still be short of usable on larger projects that uses several packages - all those projects need to be pip-installable )

The minimalist `setup.py` file is a two liner and can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-module - certainly far from "convoluted".